# Selecting WHERE text replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to select from `tblReportTitles` WHERE `ReportTitle` replaces the text "in US". My expected result is to have a the select return be the 3rd row `Online Stores` without any country at the end of it.

Currently when I am selecting:

```
WHERE i.ReportTitle = (REPLACE(i.ReportTitle, 'in US' , ''))
```

I am getting no rows returned from my query.

How can I select from table where it'll replace text and match with one in `tblReportTitles`?

Here is an example of my table:

| CountryId | ReportTitle | ReportId | IdArea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Online Stores in US | 21 | 1 |
| 2 | Online Stores in Canada | 37 | 1 |
| 3 | Online Stores | 14 | 1 |

Here is my query:

```
SELECT rpt.ReportTitle 
FROM dbo.tblReportTitles i    
JOIN dbo.tblReportTitles rpt ON rpt.IdArea = i.IdArea    
WHERE i.ReportTitle = (REPLACE(i.ReportTitle, 'in US' , ''))
  AND i.IdCountry = 1
  AND i.ReportId = 21
```

I am expecting a result that appears like:

| CountryId | ReportTitle | ReportId | IdArea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Online Stores | 14 | 1 |

Essentially I'm attempting to select from the table. Using the "Online Stores in the US" title removing the Country prefix and selecting any values in the table that has "Online Stores" I'm not sure if replace is the correct way to go about it? But I hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output , your question is not clear

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: At present, you're asking SQL to return a row WHERE i.ReportTitle equals a value where some of the characters in i.ReportTitle have been removed ..... essentially, you're asking WHERE 'Online Stores in US' = 'Online Stores' - so that is never going to return a row (because that expression will always evaluate to False).  You should also include an example of how you want the data to appear, because at the moment your query doesn't really make sense

Comment: And you really really want to avoid that sort of calculation in your where clause because its un-SARGable and as such could perform badly.

Comment: @Craig I've provided the desire results. Essentially I'm attempting to select from the table. Using the "Online Stores in the US" title removing the Country prefix and selecting any values in the table that has "Online Stores" I'm not sure if replace is the correct way to go about it? but I hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: @DaleK still working on it at the moment

Comment: @DaleK yours has helped the most, but I am getting stuck I believe is the replace logic. I'm essentially trying to select a row that has a similar word. For example, if I remove "in the US" I have the phrase "Online Stores". I'd like the row that has "Online Stores" in the title not necessarily an exact match. So it could potentially return "Online Stores in Canada" or just "Online Stores" depending on the parameters I pass. I am having issues with that last bit. Not an exact match but if it has the phrase. not sure if that makes sense

Comment: @stepheniok not really sorry, your example data doesn't match what you've just said, and I suspect your sample data is too limited to represent the entire problem. And based on what you've said above you just need `where T.ReportTitle like 'online stores%'` - but then you get all 3 rows returned. So I do think the question needs quite a bit more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . If the title are all the same for the first 13 characters, you can use `left()`:

```
select left(reporttitles, 13)
```

Or to take everything before `' in '` if the initial part can change:

```
select left(reportitle, charindex(' in ', reportitles + ' in '))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked out what you are looking for. The following returns your desired results by obtaining the desired Title using a sub-query rather than a join.

This is however a very specific solution for this country record. A more generic solution would be more complex.

```
DECLARE @ReportTitles TABLE (CountryId int, ReportTitle varchar(62), ReportId int, AreaId int);

INSERT INTO @ReportTitles (CountryId, ReportTitle, ReportId, AreaId)
VALUES
(1, 'Online Stores in US', 21, 1),
(2, 'Online Stores in Canada', 37, 1),
(3, 'Online Stores', 14, 1);

SELECT
    T.CountryId
    , T.ReportTitle
    , T.ReportId
    , T.AreaId
FROM @ReportTitles T
WHERE T.ReportTitle = (
    SELECT
        REPLACE(T1.ReportTitle, 'in US' , '')
    FROM @ReportTitles T1
    WHERE T1.CountryId = 1
    AND T1.ReportId = 21
);
```

Note the complete MRE with DDL + DML + Sample data. Doing this makes it much easier for people to assist. And gives you a chance to remove your syntax errors before posting a question (CountryId <> IdCountry).